# How do I add one value to a variable every time a date field is null?

Tags: microsoft-access, visual-basic

In Access 2013, I am working on a report. Using the `On print event`, I have a problem trying to add one value to a variable every time a date field is null. It works fine `somaValores =Somavalores + 1`

Tried `IIF` but it doesn’t work.
Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Detalhe_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
 Select Case Me!TipoMeta
    Case "Percentagem"
       Select Case Me!DtResposta
          Case Is  Me!DtLimite
             ForaPrazo = ForaPrazo + 1
*********************************************************
DTLIMITE IS A DATE TYPE FIELD 
HERE I NEED: CASE DTLIMITE = NULL THEN
CONTA = CONTA + 1 
**********************************************************
       End Select
    Case "Valores absolutos"
        SomaValores = SomaValores + 1
    Case "Data"
 End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this, but I think your are looking for `ISNULL` withing your `Case`.

```
   If IsNull (DTLIMITE) Then 
      CONTA = 1
   Else
      CONTA = CONTA + 1
   End If
```

This looks to see if the variable is null. If TRUE, it will set the variable to `1`, else it will add `1` to the existing variable value.

Comment: Select Case Me!DtResposta
          If IsNull(Me!DtResposta) Then
             SemResp = SemResp + 1
          End If
          Case Is <= Me!DtLimite
             DentroPrazo = DentroPrazo + 1
          Case Is > Me!DtLimite
             ForaPrazo = ForaPrazo + 1
       End Select

Comment: Did that work? What is your comment supposed to tell me?